# If checkbox is checked then exclude from dropdown

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Drop down
[image: Dropdown]

Checkbox
[image: Checkbox]

I'm new to Sheets so I'm open to suggestions and advice.
Sorry for the messy spreadsheet, I'm also playing with Forms and automations.

I tried looking for a FILTER formula, but I have no idea what I'm doing. I wouldn't even know where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this nice tutorial online. Basically, they advice to create an intermediate table with the selected options using the FILTER command as you suggested. After that, it is possible to select to calculated (potentially hidden) column to fill in the drop-down options.

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/create-dynamic-dependent-drop-down-excel/